# toggle kml with ArcGIS javascript api

Tags: javascript, kml, arcgis

I'm trying to use checkboxes to toggle kmls using the ArcGIS javascript API.

The example for toggling on the esri site is for a dynamic map service and I can't figure how to make it work for a kml
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/map_explicitlayerlist.html

I have added my kml here

```
  var kmlURL = 'http://www.lohneswright.com/ctc/kml/actc_wheels.kml';
  var kml = new esri.layers.KMLLayer(kmlURL);
  map.addLayer(kml);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/CheckBox.html) has a good checkbox which can toggle layers in ArcGIS Javascript.  The code below should work for what you are looking for.  You can also use the "show()" and "hide()" method(s) for the KML layer.  This will toggle them as well.

```
require(["dijit/form/CheckBox", "esri/layers/KMLLayer", "dojo/domReady!"], 
function(CheckBox, KMLLayer){

var kmlURL = 'http://www.lohneswright.com/ctc/kml/actc_wheels.kml';
var kml = new KMLLayer(kmlURL);

var checkBox = new CheckBox({
    checked: false,
    onChange: function(checked){
           if(checked){
                map.addLayer(kml);
           }else{
                map.removeLayer(kml);
           }
}, "checkBox");
});
```